# Apache2 does not proxy to port (over WireGuard)

Tags: apache, apache2, wireguard

I want to connect to file browser on my home server over Wireguard. Simple pages, like `index.html`, loads well, but web browser doesn't connect to file browser

Right now file `/etc/apache2/site-available/site-ssl.conf` look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName site.com
ServerAlias www.site.com
ServerAdmin site@localhost

ProxyRequests on

DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/chain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass "/filebrowser" "http://10.0.0.2:8082/"
ProxyPassReverse "/filebrowser" "http://10.0.0.2:8082/"
</VirtualHost>
```

On local network I can connect to file server. Browser missing port, while redirecting.
[image: Connection over domain]

[image: Connection over local]
Proxy modules installed and wireguard connection established. How to make it work?